# AS3 array of movieclip buttons with fluid animation and AT state

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, event-handling, movieclip

I wanted to setup an array of movieclip buttons to navigate across my timeline via labels, this is where it went pear shaped.

Having spent three days reading and attempting most online solutions I couldn't find a method which worked 100% without failing in some way or another.

I've had some joy with the method below having seen a blog entry covering different ways to call frames etc and which highlighted the bugbear below :

```
clipArray[i].mouseChildren = false; //Hidden bugbear
```

I've added the full code below so hopefully it may help anyone else who similarly nearly resorted to hari-kari in trying this.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var clipArray:Array = [btn_1,btn_2]; // Movieclip's called btn_1 etc...
var destArray:Array = ["page_1","page_2"]; Labels on timeline...
for (var i:int = 0; i < clipArray.length; i++) {
clipArray[i].buttonMode = true; // Define Button from Movie Clip
clipArray[i].useHandCursor = true; // Enable HandCursor over clip
clipArray[i].mouseChildren = false; // Define clip as single denomination
clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
clipArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickHandler, false, 0, true);
}

function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
for (var i:int = 0; i < clipArray.length; i++) {
    if (event.currentTarget == clipArray[i]) {
        this.gotoAndStop(destArray[i]);
        clipArray[i].mouseEnabled = false;
        clipArray[i].useHandCursor = false;
        clipArray[i].alpha = 0.5;
    } else {
        clipArray[i].mouseEnabled = true;
        clipArray[i].useHandCursor = true;
        clipArray[i].alpha = 1;
    }
}
}

function mouseOverHandler(e:MouseEvent){
e.target.onOff = true;
}

function mouseOutHandler(e:MouseEvent){
e.target.onOff = false;
}

function frameHandler(e:Event){
if(e.target.onOff){
    e.target.nextFrame();
} else {
    e.target.prevFrame();
}
}
```

This works fine, now however my understanding of whether it is 'good' code or not is an issue, if this could be improved in any way I'd like to know why and how as the problem with learning AS3 from 2 is that often you use code having seen it online without fully grasping the detail.

Tentatively, I'm pleased as this proved to be a nightmare to find or to resolve and hope it helps anyone else in a similar state of mind.

Adding MovieClip buttons with fluidity and which cancel out from an array became a three day mission when you're learning...

Answer (score 0):

You might find you have more freedom if you put all of this in a class and use the Tween class to travel to your 'labels' instead of the timeline. It would mean that you would be able to remove your event listeners until your animation has finished.

Also it looks like you might be better off using the MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER and MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT

If I'm honest I don't know what some of your methods want to do without seeing your whole project, but I've quickly written a class for you. I've replaced animating between pages with just having your buttons animate to a ramdom location. (Remember to export your MovieClips you create with the IDE into actionscript, giving them the class name Button01, Button02 etc...). I hope this sends you in the right direction :)

```
package com
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    private var btn_1:Button01 = new Button01;
    private var btn_2:Button02 = new Button02;
    private var clipArray:Array = new Array();
    private var xAxis:Number = 0;
    private var yAxis:Number = 0;
    private static const WIDTH:int = 300;
    private static const HEIGHT:int = 250;
    private var tweenButton:Tween;

    public function Main()
    {
        makeArrays();
        addChildren();
        setEventListeners()
    }
    private function makeArrays():void
    {
        for(var i:uint=0; i<2; i++)
            clipArray.push(this['btn_'+(i+1)]);
    }
    private function addChildren():void
    {
        for(var i:uint=0; i<clipArray.length; i++){
            addChild(clipArray[i]);
            clipArray[i].x = WIDTH*Math.random();
            clipArray[i].y = HEIGHT*Math.random();
        }
    }
    private function setEventListeners():void
    {
        for (var i:uint=0; i<clipArray.length; i++) {
            clipArray[i].buttonMode = true; // Define Button from Movie Clip
            //clipArray[i].useHandCursor = true; // Enable HandCursor over clip
            //clipArray[i].mouseChildren = false; // Define clip as single denomination // DON'T NEED THIS WITH ROLL_OVER
            clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
            clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
            clipArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameHandler);
            clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false, 0, true);
        }
    }
    private function tweenButtons(e:Event):void
    {
        var dispObj = e.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
        dispObj.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler)
        tweenButton = new Tween(dispObj, 'x', Regular.easeIn, dispObj.x, WIDTH*Math.random(), 1, true);
        tweenButton = new Tween(dispObj, 'y', Regular.easeIn, dispObj.y, HEIGHT*Math.random(), 1, true);
        tweenButton.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, reattachEventListener);
    }
    private function reattachEventListener(e:Event):void
    {
        tweenButton.removeEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_FINISH, reattachEventListener);
        for (var i:uint=0; i<clipArray.length; i++) {
            if(!(hasEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK)))
               clipArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler, false, 0, true);
        }
    }
    private function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        for (var i:uint=0; i<clipArray.length; i++) {
            if (e.currentTarget == clipArray[i]) {
                tweenButtons(e);
                clipArray[i].buttonMode = false
                clipArray[i].alpha = 0.5;
            } else {
                clipArray[i].buttonMode = true;
                clipArray[i].alpha = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    private function mouseOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void // I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT YOU'RE TRYING TO DO HERE
    {
        e.target.onOff = true;
    }

    private function mouseOutHandler(e:MouseEvent):void // I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT YOU'RE TRYING TO DO HERE
    {
        e.target.onOff = false;
    }

    private function frameHandler(e:Event):void // I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT YOU'RE TRYING TO DO HERE
    {
        if(e.target.onOff){
            e.target.nextFrame();
        }else{
            e.target.prevFrame();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and you're input. Its a heavy learning curve from AS2!

Personally I'm still a little unsure of how the packages thing works in Flash. As a newcomer I find it strange and am unsure of the why's and how to sort code at best, plus the differences in what I'm trying to do are easier to work out inline.

I can see the logic in your method in some ways but it's a little beyond my grasp when it's in packages. Soon hopefully.

Comment: Meanwhile, the mouseOverHandler items you were unsure of have been modified from another example i saw which enabled the mouse over to allow fluid operation of the nextFrame code.

I had real problems with either it registering either just one frame forward, or similarly the entire array working in parralel, after a day I managed to use this to enable fluid motion between the button animations whilst still navigating to through the destArray without any error reports showing.

I was so damn pleased it worked, the how became irrelevant...

Comment: I'm working on my site and it's quite heavy however the finesse in understanding some AS3 jargon is a killer and it's even more annoying when you can spot the problem but are unable to find the answer.

The Buttons I did try the ROLL_Over but must had some coding wrong somewhere as the method I put seemed to be the only way which worked  for me.

Comment: yep... ROLL_OVER will not drill down into your target's children, MOUSE_OVER will... there's a great article on it here: http://www.wastedpotential.com/flash-as3-target-vs-currenttarget/

Comment: Thanks, seems the versatility of AS3 is often overshadowed by it's complexity. Good article explaining it too.

The worse thing I find about 3 is that there are too many ways of doing the same thing and when you're learning you don't know that if it's working is always a good thing!